# 'InvalidArgumentException: URI must be a string or UriInterface in Guzzle' error when try to login

Tags: laravel, vue.js, guzzle, laravel-passport

This is my login function when I use like this Im getting URI must be string error.

When I use the code in comments in try section (I couldn't find where I found this solution) I can login normally but in this case when password is wrong the catch part does not work (it doesn't turn error) and frontend redirect to home page.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

    try {
        $response = $client->post(config('services.passport.login_endpoint'), [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => config('services.passport.client_id'),
                'client_secret' => config('services.passport.client_secret'),
                'username' => $request->username,
                'password' => $request->password,
            ]
        ]);
        return $response->getBody();


    /*    $username = $request->username;
        $password = $request->password;
        $request->request->add([
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => config('services.passport.client_id'),
            'client_secret' => config('services.passport.client_secret'),
            'scope' => '*'
        ]);

        $tokenRequest = $request->create(
            env('APP_URL').'/oauth/token',
            'post'
        );
        $response = Route::dispatch($tokenRequest);

        return ($response->getContent()); */

    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() === 400) {
            return response()->json('Invalid Request. Please enter a username or a password.', $e->getCode());
        } else if ($e->getCode() === 401) {
            return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again', $e->getCode());
        }

        return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server.', $e->getCode());
    }
}
```

Frontend Part:

```
retrieveToken(context, credentials) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.post('/login', {
      username: credentials.username,
      password: credentials.password,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        // console.log(response.data.access_token);
        const token = response.data.access_token;

        localStorage.setItem('access_token', token);
        context.commit('retrieveToken', token);
        resolve(response);
        // context.commit('addAppointment', response.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
      });
  });
},
```

Services.php file:

```
<?php

 return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Third Party Services
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is for storing the credentials for third party services such
| as Mailgun, Postmark, AWS and more. This file provides the de facto
| location for this type of information, allowing packages to have
| a conventional file to locate the various service credentials.
|
*/

'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.mailgun.net'),
],

'postmark' => [
    'token' => env('POSTMARK_TOKEN'),
],

'ses' => [
    'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
],

'passport' => [
    'login_endpoint' => env('PASSPORT_LOGIN_ENDPOINT'),
    'client_id' => env('PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('PASSPORT_CLIENT_SECRET'),
],
```

];

Comment: What's in your Services.php config file?

Comment: Also laravel has it's own HTTP client (which is a wrapper of guzzle) https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client

Comment: I added the services.php file

Comment: What does PASSPORT_LOGIN_ENDPOINT resolve to in your env file?